# Creating parallax content

Tags: html, css, parallax

Essentially, I have 3 different elements on the page (header, body, footer). I would like to keep the header and footer elements fixed `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`. They all may have variable heights body height 80%, footer height 5%, and header height 15%.

Finally, and most importantly, I want the primary scroll to only scroll the body content. I have set the `overflow: scroll` of the body, and even set `overflow: hidden` of the html. This works, except the scroll bar is only functional on the body div.

How may I set the browser scrollbar on the right hand side (primary scrollbar) to control the body div?

Comment: If your header and footer is FIXED then the primary scrollbar already controls only your body..?

Comment: Are you able to show us the relevant CSS? However, I suspect you may need to add padding: 15% 0 5% 0; to the body.